# Como criar uma checklist no trello utilizando a biblioteca Trello.net Edge

Tags: c#, trello

Estou tentando (sem sucesso) utilizar a biblioteca [Trello.Net Edge](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TrelloNet.Edge/) para criar uma checklist em um determinado *card*. O problema é que: sempre que tento criar a checkilist é retornado um erro dizendo que o valor do campo `idCard` é inválido e o método que estou consumindo não pede por este argumento. Segue abaixo o código que utilizei:

```
Board board = trello.Boards.WithId("[idBoard]");
Checklist ch = trello.Checklists.Add("Teste", board); //erro lançado nesta linha...
```

Consigo obter/incluir/alterar qualquer outra informação. Mas, não consigo mais incluir esta checklist. Segue abaixo a mensagem:

> An unhandled exception of type  'TrelloNet.TrelloException' occurred
>   in TrelloNet.dll Additional information: invalid value for idCard